# Launch of osm2pgrouting: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: osm2pgrouting

[image]I am trying to launch the osm2pgrouting thru the command below and load data (file) into it, but i get the following message:

> $ osm2pgrouting --f osnabrueck.osm --conf mapconfig.xml --dbname
> routing --username postgres Execution starts at: Tue Jul 14 14:14:01
> 2020
>
> ---
>
> ```
>        COMMAND LINE CONFIGURATION             *
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Filename = osnabrueck.osm
> Configuration file = mapconfig.xml
> host = localhost
> port = 5432
> dbname = routing
> username = postgres
> schema=
> prefix =
> suffix =
> Don't drop tables
> Don't create indexes
> Don't add OSM nodes
>
> ---
>
> Testing database connection: routing fe_sendauth: no password supplied

What does the last line mean? How do I supply password to it?

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that you are trying to connect to Postgres/PostGIS with your default user name and it is not a trusted user. You can usually, solve it by specifying the actual user you want to run this command (`postgres`) by using the `--username postgres` commandline argument. You will then be prompted for the password.

Comment: Thank you! Could you show me exactly how the command line should look like?

Comment: I tried:  sudo osm2pgrouting --f osnabrueck.osm --conf mapconfig.xml --dbname routing --username postgres
and it showed me: [sudo] password for postgres: 
postgres is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: are you already logged in as postgres? - can you [edit] your question with more details

Comment: Yes, I logged-in using: sudo su postgres.     Then it asks to enter password. Then I add the sudo command line above and I get the incident message.  If not using sudo, I receive message which I already posted: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Comment: do it as a regular user with the --username or as postgres then no sudo or --username

Comment: I have tried either way, does not work unfortunately. I have uploaded picture in the post now.

Answer (score 0):

Password command needed to be added:

osm2pgrouting --f your-OSM-XML-File.osm --conf mapconfig.xml --dbname routing --username postgres -W yourpassword --clean

Password needs to be simple with letter characters. Otherwise, if you have these symbols: !1,234, it will show: event not recognized.